# Filter options of a <select> with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a select with some values. When the user enters a vehicle in the search box, the drop down gets filtered to the option value that matches in the search box. I am able to get this first part of the code to work but the problem I am having, is how would I be able to save the option value that was filtered in the drop down so that it becomes the first option in the list. Lets say for example the user by mistake, hits the backspace button because if that happens the option value that was selected is no longer selected and the option value is defaulted back to the first option in the drop down. I am guessing to save the value I would have to use a cookie, totally lost on this part, any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

> Has to be able to work in IE5 and Up :/

```
<input type="text" id="searchFilter" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="FilterItems(this.value);" />
<select id="ddVehicles">
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="2">Mercedes-Benz</option>
    <option value="3">Bentley</option>
    <option value="4">Lamborghini</option>
</select>



var ddlText, ddlValue, ddl;
function CacheItems() {
  ddlText = new Array();
  ddlValue = new Array();
  ddl = document.getElementById("ddVehicles");
  for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
     ddlText[ddlText.length] = ddl.options[i].text;
     ddlValue[ddlValue.length] = ddl.options[i].value;
  }
}
window.onload = CacheItems;

function FilterItems(value) {
  ddl.options.length = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ddlText.length; i++) {
     if (ddlText[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1 || ddlText[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(value) != -1) {
        AddItem(ddlText[i], ddlValue[i]);
    }
  }
}

function AddItem(text, value) {
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.text = text;
  opt.value = value;
  ddl.options.add(opt);
}
```

Comment: The text values are mixed upper and lower case, but the search loop only tests against all upper and all lower case. Also, why destroy and recreate the options? DOM elements are objects, they can be removed and restored without being destroyed. You could have a `ddlOptions` array that holds references directly to the options, then adds and removes them from the select as required.

Comment: Love to read why you have to support IE 5.5 (which was last updated 16 years ago...)

Answer (score 3):

A better & fast Version by using "match"
[image]

```js
    function filter() {
        var keyword = document.getElementById("search").value;
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
            var txt = select.options[i].text;
            if (!txt.match(keyword)) {
                $(select.options[i]).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
            } else {
                $(select.options[i]).removeAttr('disabled').show();
            }

        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" style="margin: 10px;width: 165px;" onkeyup="filter()">
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="select" size="10" style="margin: 10px; width: 165px;height: 170px;">
            <option>Cupcake</option>
            <option>Cunut</option>
            <option>Eclair</option>
            <option>Froyo</option>
            <option>Gingerbread</option>
            <option>Honeycomb</option>
            <option>Ice Cream Sandwich</option>
            <option>Jelly Bean</option>
            <option>KitKat</option>
            <option>Lollipop</option>
            <option>Marshmallow</option>
            <option>Nougat</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this example is working well. Can someone please share that javascript code if someone does wnot want to use jquery?

Answer (score 2):

IE 5, wow. That browser is utterly dysfunctional on the web, so I'm assuming this is for homework. It's much better to post your code as a runnable snippet, that way it can be played with right here in SO.

I'd suggest caching the options rather than having to recreate them, and test using all lower case (or upper if you prefer) to increase the chance of a match. If the search field is empty, then restore the select to its original state.

Oh, and the convention is that variable names starting with a capital letter are constructors.

E.g.

```js
var optionsCache = [];

function filterItems(el) {
  var value = el.value.toLowerCase();
  var form = el.form;
  var opt, sel = form.ddVehicles;
  if (value == '') {
    restoreOptions();
  } else {
    // Loop backwards through options as removing them modifies the next
    // to be visited if go forwards
    for (var i=sel.options.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
      opt = sel.options[i];
      if (opt.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1){
        sel.removeChild(opt)
      }
    }
  }
}

// Restore select to original state
function restoreOptions(){
  var sel = document.getElementById('ddVehicles');
  sel.options.length = 0;
  for (var i=0, iLen=optionsCache.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    sel.appendChild(optionsCache[i]);
  }
}


window.onload = function() {
  // Load cache
  var sel = document.getElementById('ddVehicles');
  for (var i=0, iLen=sel.options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    optionsCache.push(sel.options[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="searchFilter" name="searchFilter" placeholder="Search" 
   onkeyup="filterItems(this);">
  <select id="ddVehicles" name="ddVehicles" size="4">
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="2">Mercedes-Benz</option>
    <option value="3">Bentley</option>
    <option value="4">Lamborghini</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I think the above should work in IE 5, I think it has *getElementById*. If not, you can reference the form controls using `document.forms[0].elementName`.

Comment: example is working but has a small problem. pressing e selects mercedez and bently. Pressing n that is en selects bently only. Good. Now if i rub n and be left with e again i should be able to get back mercedez and bently. Unfortunately mercecedez is not coming back to list on back space and rubbing n. Why is the rubbing not doing the expected action? Someone help with this code edit please.

Comment: Options are only restored when the search value is empty. You can fix that by removing the *if..else* and doing a restore and filter each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the option element into a data attribute on the input:

```
var select = document.getElementById("ddVehicles");
var selOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex]
document.getElementById('searchFilter').dataset.selOption = selOption
```

Alternatively you could store the option element's index, text, or even outerHTML, whatever you need.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes for more info.